# Is something arbitrary if it is a function of something else?

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, proof-explanation

I'm working through Gauss' [proof of the Normal Distribution](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Allendoerfer/stahl96.pdf) (pg 106, pdf pg 10). At this point we have:

\begin{equation*}
  f(M_1-\bar{M}) + f(M_2-\bar{M}) + \cdots + f(M_n-\bar{M}) = 0
\end{equation*}

where

\begin{equation*}
  f(x) = \frac{\phi'(x)}{\phi(x)}
\end{equation*}

and $\phi(x)$ ends up being the Normal Distribution. The author says that since $M_i$ can assume arbitrary values (it is some observation that occurs with probability determined by $\phi$) we can use $N$ and $M$ as arbitrary reals where:

$$M_1 = M, M_2=M_3=\dots=M_n = M - Nn$$

and thus the mean (which is the usual mean)

$$ \bar{M} = \frac{M_1+M_2+\dots+M_n}{n}=M-(n-1)N$$

By substitution into the first equation we find

$$f((n-1)N)=(n-1)f(N)$$

(Note that f(-x)=f(x))

and thus by homogeneity combined with the continuity of $f$ we can write:

$$f(x)=\frac{\phi'(x)}{\phi(x)}=kx$$

and integrate our way to glory.

I have some questions. Although $M$ and $N$ are arbitrary:

1. We have set the first element, $M_1$ to something arbitrary. Fine.
2. We have set every other item $M_2$ to $M_n$ equal to the same thing. Doesn't this create an assumption?
3. The thing we set those other items to is a function of both $M$ and $n$. Does that not also create an assumption?

Comment: What exactly is the result that is supposed to be proved?

Comment: See the attached document.

Comment: @William we are deriving the Normal Distribution.

Comment: What is that even supposed to mean though? It's not a theorem, it's a mathematical object. You just define it. 

What about the normal distribution is supposed to be proved? I read the relevant part of the article, but it was still unclear to me what exactly they were trying to show.

Comment: @William The Normal is derived from the three assumptions listed in the article. This is one approach, there are others. It was not just defined to be the formula we know today.

Comment: So you mean the proof is to show that "the normal distribution is the unique probability distribution satisfying these three assumptions"? What page are the assumptions on?